# Retrieving data from Sql Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, database, stored-procedures

How can I retrieve a set of data, a whole column of a table, by using an sql stored procedure?

When I execute the below procedure it gives me only the last `ID` of the `ID` column.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCariIdleri] @don int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @don = ID
FROM TBLP1CARI
END
```

`TBLCARI` has a column named `ID` and I want to take *all the values in that column* but the result gives only the last value in that column.

Comment: When you execute _what_ procedure?

Comment: i didn't add the code because it is like nothing.

Comment: Consider to add source code so we will better understand your problem...

Comment: which other columns do you want added to your output?  you need to add them to your select clause along with ID.  wait, you want more rows in your output?  you're limiting your rows by criteria @don=ID.  To get all rows, just say select ID from table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that `@don` parameter retains only the last id and is returned alone
remove it, or if you need it add another select:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCariIdleri]  

AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT ID
FROM TBLP1CARI

END
```

or

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCariIdleri]  @don int OUTPUT

AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @don = ID
FROM TBLP1CARI

SELECT ID
FROM TBLP1CARI

END
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCariIdleri]

AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT ID
FROM TBLP1CARI

END
```

Your version of the proc assigns ID to an output variable - that can only ever have one value.

Answer (score 3):

Your procedure is setting a variable @don if you want all the rows just return the results of the select.

```
Select ID
FROM TBLP1CARI
where  <criteria>
```

What actually gets returned technically depends on your RDBMS but I think its what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

to read a *grid* of data, you should use ExecuteReader(), i.e.

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    while(reader.Read()) {
        // the first column, assuming [n][var]char()
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

With a SELECT statement like:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TBLP1CARI
```

You can't select all those cells into a single output parameter since you have multiple rows; SELECT is the way to go instead.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. about reading a grid of data, it really helped me in the next steps.